# I need help solving this JDBC Exception Error, does anyone know how to solve this?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

I want to create a new Role object in a controller method, which then displays all 'Roles' from a data repository which is linked to Hibernate/H2 database but every time I try to create a new object, I get an SQL error which to me doesn't seem to be right. If anyone can help that would be great.

Here is the repo - https://github.com/danielturato/InstaTeam-th

For role entity I've tried this:

1. Changed @NotEmpty above the name field to @NotNull & vice versa
2. Added and deleted the overrided Equals, HashCode & toString methods
3. Added a builder class in the Role (didn't work)

`Role.java`

```
@Entity
public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@NotEmpty
private String name;

public Role() {}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Role role = (Role) o;
    return id == role.id &&
            Objects.equals(name, role.name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, name);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Role{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

RoleController.java:

```
@Controller
public class RoleController {

@Autowired
private RoleServiceImpl roleService;

@RequestMapping("/roles")
public String viewAllRoles(ModelMap model) {
    Role r = new Role();
    r.setName("test");
    roleService.save(r);
    List<Role> roles = roleService.findAll();
    model.put("roles", roles);

    if (!model.containsAttribute("role")) {
        model.put("role", new Role());
    }

    return "roles";
}
```

Expected:

- When I go to /roles, a new Role will be created each time and then all the roles already in the database will be displayed on the web page

Actual:

- I get an error

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "'test' (PROJECT: ID INTEGER DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR PUBLIC.SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_098E5D98_0CA5_42E8_BC1B_0E5F5AEF4194) NOT NULL NULL_TO_DEFAULT SEQUENCE PUBLIC.SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_098E5D98_0CA5_42E8_BC1B_0E5F5AEF4194)"; SQL statement:
>   insert into Role (id, name) values (null, ?) [22018-197]
>       at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:623) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
>       at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeUpdate(CommandRemote.java:237) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
>       at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:199) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
>       at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:153) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:136) ~[tomcat-dbcp-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:136) ~[tomcat-dbcp-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3083) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3676) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:375) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:681) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:673) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:668) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
>       at com.danielturato.dao.BaseDao.save(BaseDao.java:41) ~[main/:na]
>       at com.danielturato.dao.BaseDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2478dae.invoke() ~[main/:na]
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at com.danielturato.dao.RoleDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6e10127a.save() ~[main/:na]
>       at com.danielturato.service.RoleServiceImpl.save(RoleServiceImpl.java:28) ~[main/:na]
>       at com.danielturato.web.RoleController.viewAllRoles(RoleController.java:27) ~[main/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_172]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_172]

Comment: Post the DDL of your table

Comment: change int id for long id and remove your strategy .. @GeneratedValue private long id;

Comment: I don't have a DDL as the table was auto created but I have this: https://gyazo.com/a6a9ff94317f75062498b170d821d5ac

Comment: I changed the int id to long id and removed the strategy and the same error occurred

Comment: can you share on some repo? @Daniel

Comment: here you go - https://github.com/danielturato/InstaTeam-th @JonathanJohx

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem is with the default system sequence. You could create a separate sequence and instead of using `GenerationType.IDENTITY` use `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`.

`CREATE SEQUENCE role_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "roleSeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "roleSeq", sequenceName = "role_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private int id;
```

let me know if this works.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work and I still get the same error